Towards a Girsanov transformation for fractional SDEs
Consider $X_t$ and $Y_t$ unidimensional processes solutions of
$$
d X_t = b^X(X_t,t) d t + \sigma d B_t,  
\mbox{ and } 
d Y_t = b^Y(Y_t,t) d t + \sigma d B_t.
$$
Here $B$ is a Brownian motion, $\sigma > 0$ is a constant. The drift $b^X$ and $b^Y$ are appropriate functions for having a strong solution.
If I am not mistaken, Girsanov transformation tells us that for any function $\Phi$ continuous and bounded on the sample paths on $[0,T]$,
$$ 
\mathbb{E} \Phi(X) = \mathbb{E} \left [ \Phi(Y) \exp \left ( -\frac{1}{\sigma}\int_0^T \left ( b^Y(Y_t,t) - b^X(Y_t,t) \right ) d B_t - \frac{1}{2 \sigma} \int_0^T ( b^Y(Y_t,t) - b^X(Y_t,t) )^2 d t \right ) \right ]  
$$
If we replace $B$ by $B^H, H \in (0,1)$ a fractional Brownian motion, what would be the corresponding formula? Are they the same where we just replace $B$ by $B^H$?
